# unable to run cucumber test using maven build run configuration

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to run cucumber tests in eclipse using maven build as run configuration. 
When i run the configuration, build is getting success but browser does not invoke. Hence the test is not running.
Tests are getting skipped, giving an info "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date".
I am able to run the same test successfully by running the feature file as cucumber feature.

Please suggest me why tests are getting skipped. Also let me know the steps for running the cucumber test as maven build. 
Below is the pom.xml that i am using. 
Also i am using vm arguments as "-Dcucumber.Options=--format html:target/cucumber-html-report --tags @Runme"

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <groupId>Maven.Project</groupId>
  <artifactId>testMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Maven.Project-v1-testMaven</name>


    <properties>
        <corporate.test.url>http://google.com</corporate.test.url>
        <corporate.test.browser>Firefox</corporate.test.browser>
        <corporate.selenium.url>http://localhost:8888/wd/hub</corporate.selenium.url>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <corporate.test.url>http://acc-about.hm.com</corporate.test.url>
                <corporate.test.browser>Firefox</corporate.test.browser>
                <corporate.selenium.url>http://localhost:8888/wd/hub</corporate.selenium.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you show the package structure of your project and where the test runner and feature files reside?

Comment: I am not able to upload the image due to less reputation here. But i have created feature file under src/test/resources and step definition and runner class files under src/test/java.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the skiptests tag in your maven - surefire plugin...

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.10</version>
<configuration>
       <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**
please add the following lines in configuration

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
<reportsDirectory>./test-output/archive/${timestamp}</reportsDirectory>
```

In here suiteXmlFile points to your xml file you are trying to run and reportsDirectory points to your output folder. In command line or if using eclipse in goal provide clean test -DsuiteFile=

Hope tthis would help.

Comment: After removing skiptest, 0 test are run. Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: Hi @shruti...I have updated the answer, please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I am able to run test now. Issue was related to naming convention. Tests should end with "test" though i was using surefire plugin. Somehow i did not face this issue on intelliJ but it occurred in Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get u..."Tests should end with test" in a sense?

Comment: say for example, your runner class file should be named as "CukeRunnerTest.java"